# How should i use the package declaration and the import Scanner statment in the top line ? As both should be declare in the first line of code

Tags: java, package

How should i declare the import statment and package declaration at the same line (i.e top of the code)?

```
package b;  
import java.util.Scanner.*;
import a.*;

public class Session27P1
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number");
        int xc = input.nextInt();
        Frog frog1 = new Frog();
        frog1.showAge(xc);
        int year = frog1.showAge();
        System.out.println(year);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The convention is to declare the package statement first then your import statements. The "top of the code" phrase (for all intents and purposes) is mainly referring to the statements being outside of the actual class.

Answer (score 0):

Just the way you wrote it. `package` first, then the list of `import`s. See [Oracle's code conventions for Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141855.html#277):

> **§3.1.2 Package and Import Statements**
>
> The first non-comment line of most Java source files is a package
>   statement. After that, import statements can follow. For example:
>
> ```
> package java.awt;
>
> import java.awt.peer.CanvasPeer;
> ```